# How to limit the amount of the loop

Tags: smarty

I am a new guy in smarty.This piece of code will loop all the list,but I just want 10 items, is there anyway to solve this problem in smarty? Thanks!

```
<ul>
    {section name=list loop=$list.list}
        <li><span><a href="/?page=article_detail&co_sn={$list.list[list].co_sn}">{$list.list[list].co_title|truncate:20:"...":true}</a></span></li>
    {/section}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `max` attribute:

```
<ul>
    {section name=list loop=$list.list max=10}
        <li><span><a href="/?page=article_detail&co_sn={$list.list[list].co_sn}">{$list.list[list].co_title|truncate:20:"...":true}</a></span></li>
    {/section}
</ul>
```

This and other Smarty section attribute settings can be found in the [Smarty Section Docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl)